# bootstrap datapicker how set body background color

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins, datepicker

In my bootstrap project I'm using bootstrap datepicker plugin [demo here](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker)
It's work very well with the default bootstrap theme (white body background) but if I use a different theme  [bootswatch slate](https://bootswatch.com/slate/) that have a dark body background the datepicker body background window is all dark and the numbers do not read.
I tried to watch the datapicker3.css, but I couldn't find anything that references to the window body background color.
How do I set the datepicker window body background color?
Thanks

Comment: .datepicker{
    background-color: red;
} 

Might be your answer

Comment: @GregoryWullimann - I already tried, but unfortunately the body remains dark, only add a simil border red.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested I found the solution

```
.datepicker.dropdown-menu table  {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```